# Using .json file as dict for making a picture with turtle not working [TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable] [Python 3.1]

Tags: dictionary, typeerror, package.json, python-turtle, python-3.10

here is my code:

```
# import statements
import random
import turtle
import json


def get_data() -> dict:
    with open('data.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data


def generate_point(x, y, cff) -> tuple:
    x1 = cff[0]*x + cff[1]*y + cff[4]
    y1 = cff[2]*x + cff[3]*y + cff[5]
    return x1, y1


def random_select(pb, cff) -> list:
    r = random.random()
    for i in range(len(pb)):
        if r < pb[i]:
            return cff[i]
        r -= pb[i]


def initialize():
    turtle.reset()
    turtle.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, 1, 1)
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.tracer(0, delay=None)


def plot(x, y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.dot(3)
    turtle.update()


def draw(pb, cff, n):
    x, y = 0, 0
    for i in range(n):
        cff = random_select(pb, cff)
        x, y = generate_point(x, y, cff)
        plot(x, y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = get_data()
    n = int(turtle.numinput('Number of Iterations',
                            'How many iterations would you like to use?',
                            default=100, minval=1, maxval=100000))
    option = int(turtle.numinput('Option Types',
                                 'Do you want to use option type 1, 2, or 3?',
                                 default=1, minval=1, maxval=3))
    initialize()
    if option == 1:
        draw(data['p0'], data['c0'], n)
    elif option == 2:
        draw(data['p1'], data['c1'], n)
    elif option == 3:
        draw(data['p2'], data['c2'], n)
    turtle.update()
```

Here is the data.json file:

```
{
    "p0": [
        0.33,
        0.33,
        0.34
    ],
    "c0": [
        [
            0.5,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.5,
            0.0
        ],
        [
            0.5,
            0.0,
            0.5,
            0.0,
            0.5,
            0.0
        ],
        [
            0.5,
            0.0,
            0.25,
            0.0,
            0.5,
            0.433
        ]
    ],
    "p1": [
        0.01,
        0.85,
        0.07,
        0.07
    ],
    "c1": [
        [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.5,
            0.0,
            0.16,
            0.0
        ],
        [
            0.85,
            0.04,
            0.075,
            -0.04,
            0.85,
            0.18
        ],
        [
            0.2,
            -0.26,
            0.4,
            0.23,
            0.22,
            0.045
        ],
        [
            -0.15,
            0.28,
            0.575,
            0.26,
            0.24,
            -0.086
        ]
    ],
    "p2": [
        0.1,
        0.1,
        0.2,
        0.2,
        0.2,
        0.2
    ],
    "c2": [
        [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.55,
            0.0,
            0.6,
            0.0
        ],
        [
            -0.05,
            0.0,
            0.525,
            -0.5,
            0.0,
            0.75
        ],
        [
            0.46,
            -0.15,
            0.27,
            0.39,
            0.38,
            0.105
        ],
        [
            0.47,
            -0.15,
            0.265,
            0.17,
            0.42,
            0.465
        ],
        [
            0.43,
            0.26,
            0.29,
            -0.25,
            0.45,
            0.625
        ],
        [
            0.42,
            0.26,
            0.29,
            -0.35,
            0.31,
            0.525
        ]
    ]
}
```

Here is the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/pythonProject7/pb4.py", line 67, in <module>
    draw(data['p1'], data['c1'], n)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/pythonProject7/pb4.py", line 51, in draw
    x, y = generate_point(x, y, cff)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/pythonProject7/pb4.py", line 19, in generate_point
    x1 = cff[0]*x + cff[1]*y + cff[4]
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I was trying to make a drawing using turtle module using coefficients and probabilities from the data.json file. It's for a project, so I can't change the data.json file just so you know. But anyways I can make the input just fine but the turtle screen immediately crashes after one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your problem is in your `draw()` routine where you redefine `cff` inside the loop, but that redefinition is used for the next iteration where you likely want the original `cff`:

```
def draw(pb, cff, n):
    x, y = 0, 0
    for i in range(n):
        cff = random_select(pb, cff)
        x, y = generate_point(x, y, cff)
        plot(x, y)
```

as the redefined `cff` has different structure than the original.  Perhaps something like:

```
def draw(pb, cff, n):
    x, y = 0, 0

    for _ in range(n):
        new_cff = random_select(pb, cff)
        x, y = generate_point(x, y, new_cff)
        plot(x, y)
```

The entire code that I reworked during the debugging process:

```
from random import random
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from json import load

def get_data():
    with open('data.json') as f:
        data = load(f)

    return data

def generate_point(x, y, cff):
    x1 = cff[0] * x + cff[1] * y + cff[4]
    y1 = cff[2] * x + cff[3] * y + cff[5]

    return x1, y1

def random_select(pb, cff):
    r = random()

    for i, element in enumerate(pb):
        if r < element:
            return cff[i]
        r -= element

    return None

def initialize():
    screen.reset()
    screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, 1, 1)

def plot(x, y):
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.dot(3)

    screen.update()

def draw(pb, cff, n):
    x, y = 0, 0

    for _ in range(n):
        new_cff = random_select(pb, cff)
        x, y = generate_point(x, y, new_cff)
        plot(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = get_data()

    screen = Screen()

    n = int(screen.numinput('Number of Iterations', \
        'How many iterations would you like to use?', default=100, minval=1, maxval=100000))

    option = int(screen.numinput('Option Types', \
        'Do you want to use option type 1, 2, or 3?', default=1, minval=1, maxval=3))

    screen.tracer(False)

    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.penup()

    initialize()

    if option == 1:
        draw(data['p0'], data['c0'], n)
    elif option == 2:
        draw(data['p1'], data['c1'], n)
    elif option == 3:
        draw(data['p2'], data['c2'], n)

    screen.tracer(True)
    screen.exitonclick()
```